# Why is BitmapFactory.decodeResource() slower when I put the images in the drawable folder?

Tags: android, image, android-resources

I've just noticed while checking some decoding times of some resource images,
that the `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` function is about 3-6 times slower, when I move the resource image to the `drawable` folder.

**Question:**

Does anybody know why this happens? Are the images scaled even if they are in the `drawable` folder? Is it possible to prevent this without storing a copy of the image in each folder?

**Details:**

I used the following code just to check the decoding times of an image.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.welcome_01);
    Log.i(TAG, "Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}
```

*Bitmap Size:* *774 x 1280*

*Device: Nexus 6* (which uses the drawable-xxxhdpi folder if the resource is available)

**Test results:**

If the image is in the `drawable` folder these are the decoding times:

```
08-03 09:18:01.072: I/MainActivity(26242): Time: 298
08-03 09:18:01.352: I/MainActivity(26242): Time: 280
08-03 09:18:01.656: I/MainActivity(26242): Time: 304
08-03 09:18:01.929: I/MainActivity(26242): Time: 272
08-03 09:18:02.263: I/MainActivity(26242): Time: 334
```

If they are in the `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder these are the results:

```
08-03 09:19:49.733: I/MainActivity(26456): Time: 54
08-03 09:19:49.786: I/MainActivity(26456): Time: 53
08-03 09:19:49.841: I/MainActivity(26456): Time: 54
08-03 09:19:49.905: I/MainActivity(26456): Time: 64
08-03 09:19:49.966: I/MainActivity(26456): Time: 61
```

Comment: Based on [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), if you put your image inside `/drawable`, the system assumes that default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which is a normal screen size and a medium-density. So it will scale up the file if your phone is xxxhdpi.

Comment: So basically it does not matter if I put the image in the drawable or the mdpi folder, if the image isn't in any other folder?

Comment: As far I as know, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my Problem.

It might help someone else.

**Solution:**

Putting the image into `drawable-nodpi` folder prevents the image to be scaled.

**Additional Infos:**

In every other folder the images are scaled in this case,
even in the `drawable` folder.

I've checked the bitmap sizes after decoding the resource inside the different folders.

*original size 774x1280*

```
drawable folder: Bitmap: 2709x4480
drawable-ldpi :  Bitmap: 3612x5973
drawable-mdpi: Bitmap: 2709x4480
drawable-hdpi:  Bitmap: 1806x2987
drawable-xhdpi:  Bitmap: 1355x2240
drawable-xxhdpi: Bitmap: 903x1493
drawable-xxxhdpi: Bitmap: 677x1120
drawable-nodpi:  Bitmap: 774x1280
```

Thanks to [Joey Chong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4173117/joey-chong) I found the official answer to the problem. On the [android developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page you can read the following lines:

> If resources are not available in the correct density, the system
>   loads the default resources and scales them up or down as needed to
>   match the current screen's density. The system assumes that default
>   resources (those from a directory without configuration qualifiers)
>   are designed for the baseline screen density (mdpi), unless they are
>   loaded from a density-specific resource directory. Pre-scaling is,
>   thus, what the system does when resizing a bitmap to the appropriate
>   size for the current screen density.

**In short** - If you don't provide a density, android handles them as mdpi.

Comment: @Glenn-- I think he has inverted the list. xxxhdpi needs the biggest size and ldpi the lowest :-P

Comment: Everything is correct. If I put the image in the ldpi folder the bitmap gets upscaled because a high res devices was used, which usually uses an other folder. I know I was confused too...

Comment: I think we've just found a weak spot in the Android Framework. This is wasted power. Why upscale an image that never gets used anyway?

Comment: @tim687, I don't think it is a weak spot in Android Framework. As per documentation, if you put a image in /drawable folder, system will assume that image is for mdpi. If a phone requested for xxxhdpi, then it will scale up to 4x.

Comment: @JoeyChong So the scaling will only happen if the system requested that xxxhdpi file?

Comment: the scaling will happen either up or down if it is not mdpi.